# Prevent deep linking working all the time

Tags: flutter, xcode, deep-linking

In my iOS mobile application, in xcode I have put my associated domain as `applinks:abc.com`

My apple-app-site-association file has

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "aaa.iosapp",
                "paths": [ "/confirm/*" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The problem is when the user click any link containing abc.com it open up the application.

What I want to do is **only open** the app when the user click on link *abc.com/confirm*.

Other time I want the users to go to abc.com website.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: add another entry to the details array:  ``{ "appID": "aaa.iosapp", "paths": [ "/confirm" ] }`` and check. It should now only open the app when the link is ``aaa.iosapp/confirm`` and for any other link, it'll be handled by the browser

Comment: the confirm link is like www.abc.com/confirm/1122... with ID , so /confirm/* seems correct right? so how to make all other links open the website?

Comment: try as I said in my above comment.